# Get authorization header from Http Interceptor

Tags: angular, header, authorization, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

I have made authorization which puts the token to `headers` directly. How can I now get this token from Angular 4 `Http Interceptor`?

[image]

Unfortunately none of below `console logs` includes this header:

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    //const changedReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbkB3cC5wbCIsImV4cCI6MTUxMDY2NDM0M30.0iBktdr4-1EzTi1iaQOOfguK7HGVJF7JYkB-AF3uZgJrmKnVESAyKkHoNRzum1Pq5xZ6GJaZC9cbZQ2umMSfLA')});
    console.log('req', req);
    return next.handle(req).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      console.log('event', event);
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        // do stuff with response if you want
      }
    }, (err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          this.ehs.setService(err.status, err.error);
          // redirect to login
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: try logging `event.headers` in HttpResponse branch

Answer (score 5):

[`HttpHeaders`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders) is a wrapper for [`Map` instance](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.0.0/packages/common/http/src/headers.ts#L23), so existing headers won't be displayed in `console.log` output, because `Map` values aren't exposed.

Headers can be retrieved from `HttpHeaders` instance, as its API suggests:

```
req.headers.get('authorization');
```