# cant get request header from angular interceptor

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I have added a new custom property to the request header as following:

```
   const headers = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer my-token', 'My-Custom-Header': 'foobar' };
    return this._http.post(environment.grow_backend + '/sourceURL', personData, { headers })
```

I can see it from the network request header

But in the interceptor intercept method it looks like the headers list is empty:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47120978/5107490 `request.headers.get('My-Custom-Header');`